# How should I structure this logic in Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I'd like to keep track of how many times a user has viewed videos in the last 24 hours. I say "videos", because a user can view more than one video.

This also means the key will expire after 24 hours. Thinking my key should look like:

```
users/1/videos/4/count/12
```

The structure should contain the user id, video id, and the count. Feel free to suggest a better key structure.

I was thinking of using a [set](http://redis.io/commands#set). Or is there a better alternative I should consider? Maybe a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you going to expire key after 24 hours? Are you only counting from midnight to midnight or are you counting views for 24 hours back from *now*? In the second case expiring the key would be wrong because if you look at the results at 16:00 you would only get results for the latest 16 hours not 24 as you want.

I would save `Strings` with keys: `video:ID:user:ID:hour`

Example: `video:31245:user:15:16` with value `2`

This tells you that user with an ID `15` has viewed video with an ID `31245` from `16:00 to 16:59` for `2` times.

If you want the 24 hour results you get the current hour and grab all they keys for previous 24 hours and sum up the values.

Then in the end every key should expire in 24 hours.

˙

Hope this helps you a bit! :)

Comment: I need to explire the key 24 hours since the key was created. Not from mignight to midnight

Comment: That's exactly what I described. Your solution doesn't capture the whole 24 hours.

Comment: Why not? I can set `expire at` to `24.hours.from_now`. Shouldn't that do it?

Comment: Let's say you start counting this data "users/1/videos/4/count/1" and after 24 hours it looks like this "users/1/videos/4/count/12" then it gets deleted. New entry is created right after that because the user saw the video again "users/1/videos/4/count/1" and after that you request the number of times this user viewed the video in 24 hours and it's 1. That is not right is it? You can't track views like this if you want the functionality you described.

Comment: By the way your key "users/1/videos/4/count/12" looks strange? What exactly is the key here and what is data? If this whole things is the key what is data suppose too look like and what will you store there?